# Chain of direct summands

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, idempotents

Let $M$ be a right $R$-module and $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq...$ a chain of direct summands, so there are submodules $B_i$ such that $A_i\oplus B_i=M$.

Is then $B_1\supseteq B_2\supseteq...$? And why or why not?

I know that I can write $A_i$ as $f_i(M)$ for $f_i\in End_R(M)$ with $f_i^2=f_i$ and that then $B_i=(1-f_i)(M)$ but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: There's no reason why the $B_i$ should form a chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is typically not true.  For instance, let $M=R^3$ and let $A_1$ be the submodule generated by $(1,0,0)$ and $A_2$ be the submodule generated by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$.  Then the submodule $B_1$ generated by $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ is a complement of $A_1$ and the submodule $B_2$ generated by $(1,0,1)$ is a complement of $A_2$, but $B_2\not\subseteq B_1$.

However, if you are allowed to *choose* the $B_i$, you can always arrange for them to form a chain.  Starting with a choice of $B_1$ and $B_2$, replace $B_2$ with $B_2'=(1-f_1)(B_2)$.  Then $B_2'$ is another complement of $A_2$ (I'll leave this for you to check), and $B_2'\subseteq B_1$.  You can then similarly replace $B_3$ with another complement $B_3'$ of $A_3$ such that $B_3'\subseteq B_2'$, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was searching for. I checked, that $B_2'$ defines a complement of $A_2$ but I'm not quite sure how to define $B_3'$. Just taking $(1-f_2)(B_3)$ doesn't seems to be the right way, then it is a subset of $B_2$ and not of $B_2'$?

Comment: Take $(1-f_2')(B_3)$, where $f_2'$ is the projection onto $A_2$ for the direct sum decomposition $A_2\oplus B_2'$.